# why is column display order changed in json_agg funtion than that of a temp table - PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I am creating a temp table in a PostgreSQL function\proc.

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE tbl_temp_class(id SERIAL PRIMARY key, batch_id INT, class_id INT, class_name VARCHAR);
```

later I am dynamically adding columns to this table, using dynamic sql.
the **l_column_counter** is incremented with in a for loop untill **n**

```
l_sql_query := CONCAT('ALTER TABLE tbl_temp_class ADD column ', 'col', '_', l_column_counter, ' varchar default('''');');
EXECUTE l_sql_query;
```

At then end I want the tbl_temp_class result as a json array. Hence I'm doing below.

```
select json_agg(ut)
  from (
select * 
  from tbl_temp_class
 order by id) ut;
```

I expect the result for the above query to be

```
[ 
 {
     "id":1,
     "batch_id":1,
     "class_id":1,
     "class_name":"Maths",
     "col_1":"",
     "col_2":"",
     "col_3":"",
     "col_4":"",
     "col_5":""
  },
  {
     "id":2,
     "batch_id":1,
     "class_id":2,
     "class_name":"History",
     "col_1":"",
     "col_2":"",
     "col_3":"",
     "col_4":"",
     "col_5":""
  }
]
```

however, the result I am getting is as below. The column display order is scrambled.
Any idea how to fix this? Is this because the json is generated out of a temp table?
I need the column display order in the final json array to be same as the column display order in the temp table.

```
[ 
 {
     "id":1,
     "col_1":"",
     "col_2":"",
     "col_3":"",
     "col_4":"",
     "col_5":"",
     "class_id":1,
     "batch_id":1,
     "class_name":"Maths",
  },
  {
     "id":2,
     "col_1":"",
     "col_2":"",
     "col_3":"",
     "col_4":"",
     "col_5":"",
     "class_id":2,
     "batch_id":1,
     "class_name":"History",
  }
]
```

Comment: The order of keys in a JSON object is irrelevant

Comment: thanks for the info, But is there any way i am enforce the order for my special case?

Comment: @VIRIYALANARESH I would expect a json built by `json_build_object` to preserve the order of properties - but you'd probably need dynamic sql again to use that

Answer (score 0):

Did you try an ORDER BY in the aggregation?

```
SELECT json_agg(ut ORDER BY id) -- this where you want to use the ORDER BY
  FROM (
SELECT * 
  FROM tbl_temp_class
 ORDER BY id) ut;
```

Comment: The question is about the order of the columns, not about the order of the rows.